# Wifi not working in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 15.04, broadcom

Yesterday I have made some updates and upgraded my linux 14.10 to linux 15.04.. Now I can't connect to my home wifi, and the others i get a dns_probe_finished_no_internet.. In the network-manager appears some really weak connections, but not my own which is 1 meter away and working because i can use my smartphone with it.

The Laptop is a Toshiba L650 and the wireless driver is a broadcom Corporation BCM4313..

Is this possible to repair? I have tried some things that appeared on google but nothing seems to work.

EDIT:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Askey Computer Corp. Device [144f:7175]
Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

EDIT2: uname -a

```
Linux ruben-toshiba 3.19.0-18-generic #18-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 19 18:31:35 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer     required:
linux-image-generic thermald
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
bcmwl-kernel-source
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 861 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1509 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8038 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package bcmwl-kernel-source.
(Reading database ... 297447 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu2) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.248+bdcom DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.19.0-18-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.19.0-18-generic
Done.

wl:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod.........

DKMS: install completed.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu15) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-18-generic
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Did you manually install a driver for the WiFi adapter? If yes, you may have to reinstall the driver, if a kernel update happened, which is quite likely if you did a release upgrade. If this is the problem, it can be avoided in future by using [DKMS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/408605/what-does-dkms-do-how-do-i-use-it)

Comment: it was automatic.. edited for the output

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/97368/402801 try this.. its quite dated, but it might help OR THIS: http://askubuntu.com/a/38700/402801 I was troubleshooting one PC with broadcom adapter similar way and it's working now...

Comment: tried them both and its still not working

Comment: I can confirm the same bug, my laptop crashes completely if I connect to a WPA1 wifi.
HP Folio 13 WM
S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason I had to change my wi-fi security from WPA and WPA2 to only WPA2... With that I can find my home wi-fi with no problems..

Answer (score 0):

If you have a wired network connection run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

If not use [THIS GUIDE](https://askubuntu.com/a/626653/167850) to install the drivers offline.

Comment: I think I've tried that already and didn't work

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? Did it install? Or give some error? Do you have a wired connection? Did you download the file? What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: After doing that the problem persisted... I have a wired connection.. 15.04 is my ubuntu version

Comment: Please [edit} your initial question and add there output of `uname -a` command and `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source` command. The driver does not install. We need to know why.

Comment: initial question edited

Comment: Now it is install corretly. `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` shoul show `wl` as a driver. And wifi must work.

Comment: 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Askey Computer Corp. Device [144f:7175]
 Kernel driver in use: wl

That's what i get.. wifi is there, but not finding my home wireless... only weak signals...

Comment: I have rebooted now and wifi is not working and that command gives following...

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Askey Computer Corp. Device [144f:7175]
3f:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers [8086:2c62] (rev 02)

Comment: I think the adapter is broken. Or bad contact with motherboard

Comment: It cant be... It is working on Windows.. Its a dual boot