# Wifi not working in Ubuntu 16.04 realtek

Tags: drivers, wireless, hp, realtek-wireless

The wifi was working properly and now it doesn’t seem to work or stopped working itself.
Here is the output of few commands

```
$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: 80:ce:62:10:82:02
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.0.103 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b1104000-b1104fff memory:b1100000-b1103fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1000000-b100ffff

$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
    Kernel modules: wl
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Tried this too:

```
$ sudo apt install build-essential dkms git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.1ubuntu2).
dkms is already the newest version (2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.5).
git is already the newest version (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.5).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.13.0-37 linux-headers-4.13.0-37-generic
  linux-headers-4.13.0-43 linux-headers-4.13.0-43-generic
  linux-headers-4.13.0-45 linux-headers-4.13.0-45-generic
  linux-headers-4.15.0-30 linux-headers-4.15.0-30-generic
  linux-headers-4.15.0-32 linux-headers-4.15.0-32-generic
  linux-headers-4.15.0-33 linux-headers-4.15.0-33-generic
  linux-image-4.13.0-37-generic linux-image-4.13.0-43-generic
  linux-image-4.13.0-45-generic linux-image-4.15.0-30-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-32-generic linux-image-4.15.0-33-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-37-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-43-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-45-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-30-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-32-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-33-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-30-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-32-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-33-generic linux-signed-image-4.13.0-37-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.13.0-43-generic linux-signed-image-4.13.0-45-generic
  linux-signed-image-generic-hwe-16.04
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 47 not upgraded.
$ git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8723de.git
fatal: destination path 'rtl8723de' already exists and is not an empty directory.
$ sudo dkms add ./rtl8723de
Error! DKMS tree already contains: rtl8723de-5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
$ sudo dkms build rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area....
'make' all KVER=4.15.0-36-generic......(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8723de: 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/make.log for more information.
nishanthr@vision:~$ sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area....
'make' all KVER=4.15.0-36-generic....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8723de: 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/make.log for more information.
```

Also tried this Larry Finger's:

```
$ sudo apt install git dkms
[sudo] password for nishanthr: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
dkms is already the newest version (2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.5).
git is already the newest version (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.5).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.13.0-37 linux-headers-4.13.0-37-generic
  linux-headers-4.13.0-43 linux-headers-4.13.0-43-generic
  linux-headers-4.13.0-45 linux-headers-4.13.0-45-generic
  linux-headers-4.15.0-30 linux-headers-4.15.0-30-generic
  linux-headers-4.15.0-32 linux-headers-4.15.0-32-generic
  linux-headers-4.15.0-33 linux-headers-4.15.0-33-generic
  linux-image-4.13.0-37-generic linux-image-4.13.0-43-generic
  linux-image-4.13.0-45-generic linux-image-4.15.0-30-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-32-generic linux-image-4.15.0-33-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-37-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-43-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-45-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-30-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-32-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-33-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-30-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-32-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-33-generic linux-signed-image-4.13.0-37-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.13.0-43-generic linux-signed-image-4.13.0-45-generic
  linux-signed-image-generic-hwe-16.04
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 47 not upgraded.
$ git clone -b extended --single-branch https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
fatal: destination path 'rtlwifi_new' already exists and is not an empty directory.
$ sudo dkms add rtlwifi_new
Error! DKMS tree already contains: rtlwifi-new-0.6
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
$ sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area....(bad exit status: 2)
make KERNELRELEASE=4.15.0-36-generic -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-36-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtlwifi-new: 0.6 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/make.log for more information.
```

Please help, any more command outputs you need I'll add.

Comment: I tried this ,the problem still persists

Comment: I have edited my answer including the output of the above command.

Comment: I have no idea ,when I _tried_ _this_ it the output was that the package already exists

Comment: Yes , I have edited my answer with the outcomes.

Comment: You have kernel v4.15.0-36 and the solution you tried won't work because of the new kernel incompatibility. You should try the answer applicable to the kernel you have.

Comment: I did try answer applicable to the kernel version looking t the comments in that answer and these were the outcomes and the problem still persists.

Comment: I have added Larry Finger's modules outcomes in the question now

Comment: You need to clean up the residues of your previous adventures before trying to install another module.

Comment: What do I do now?

Comment: `dkms status` will give you installed modules, you can remove using `dkms remove`. Refer to this first: https://askubuntu.com/questions/408605/what-does-dkms-do-how-do-i-use-it and also `man dkms`.