# How do I use the microphone of the Droidcam work

Tags: sound, android, microphone, webcam

I followed the instruction on https://randomblog.hu/using-your-android-phone-as-a-webcam-for-ubuntu-20-04-with-droidcam/ to download the droidcam to a directory on my Ubunto PC. I ran the following commands in succession:

```
sudo ./install-client
sudo ./install-dkms
sudo ./install-video
```

On the second command sudo ./install-dkms, I got the error ./install-dkms: line 32: dkms: command not found. I still proceeded with the third command, install-video.

The DroidCam installed and I installed the DroidCam app on my Android phone. I entered the IP on the DroidCam on my Ubuntu desktop. I was able to make a test video call. The video was displaying but the audio on the microphone was not working. How do I get the microphone to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `./install-dkms: line 32: dkms: command not found` is important, and is why later things aren't working. You need this command to work successfully for Droidcam to work. See [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/408605/1438484) for what `dkms` is.

To install `dkms`, run `sudo apt install dkms`. Reboot, and then try the script again.