# Installing a new kernel built from source takes too much time

Tags: kernel, compiling

I have built Linux kernel from source with `make` and `make modules_install`. But I issue the `install` command:

```
$ sudo make -j8 V=1 install
arch/x86/Makefile:142: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (        \
echo >&2;                           \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
echo >&2 ;                          \
/bin/false)
sh ./arch/x86/boot/install.sh 5.15.10 \
    arch/x86/boot/bzImage System.map "/boot"
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 5.15.10 /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.10
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 5.15.10 /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.10
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.15.10                                                      
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area......
make KERNELRELEASE=5.15.10 all INCLUDEDIR=/lib/modules/5.15.10/build/include KVERSION=5.15.10 DKMS_BUILD=1
...
```

This command goes on for hours. What is really going?

Comment: @Nmath why would this be about Arch? The `./arch` there is the subdirectory of the kernel build tree. It is shorthand for "architecture" as in "x86 architecture", it isn't about Arch Linux.

Comment: You perhaps need a better processor? I run a 2nd gen threadripper and a recent kernel takes about 7 minutes: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/kernel-build-time-4175691322/page2.html#post6226386

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the output you show, it looks like your machine is recompiling all of the kernel modules you have, to work with the new kernel. That's what `dkms` ([Dynamic Kernel Module Support](https://askubuntu.com/q/408605/85695)) does. Since this is compilation, it is expected to take quite a long time.

As long as you keep seeing output there (there should be various compilation messages), there should be no problem and it will finish. Eventually.

Comment: The problem is that it cleans the build area, and therefore the whole kernel is again built by this service (`dkms`). On top of that, it does not parallelize the whole process and takes a lot of time. How to parallelize the build process?

And is there anyway to not use this `installkernel` approach to deploy a new kernel? I just want to deploy the newly built kernel with a procedure to build all the kernel modules with the new kernel. `dkms` tries to automate the process, but it is very slow and unnecessarily cleans the build area.